# How to add to payload-expression two pathVariables?

Tags: java, spring-integration

I have inbound-channel-adapter with path and one pathVariables but now I would like to add the second variable and can\t find how it should look in payload.

I found this solution but I don't want my variables to be in headers:

```
<int-http:inbound-gateway id="restCall"
                          request-channel="jobRunner"
                          supported-methods="POST"
                          path="/etl/{jobName}/{currentCustomer}">
    <int-http:header name="jobName" expression="#pathVariables.jobName"/>
    <int-http:header name="currentCustomer"/>
 </int-http:inbound-gateway>
```

I need something like:

```
 <int-http:inbound-gateway id="restCall"
                          request-channel="jobRunner"
                          supported-methods="POST"
                          path="/etl/{jobName}/{currentCustomer}"
                          payload-expression = 
 "#pathVariables.jobName,#pathVariables.currentCustomer">                              
  </int-http:inbound-gateway>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The payload is a single object; it can't be two.

You can either add one of the variables to a `<header/>` instead, or create some POJO and use

```
"new com.foo.MyVariableContainer(#pathVariables.jobName, #pathVariables.currentCustomer)"
```

Comment: You also may use *inline maps* from SpEL: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.1.8.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/core.html#expressions-inline-maps. So, this way your payload in the message would be as a standard `Map`. On the other hand, please, share what do you expect? What is your payload should be as a result of that expression (which is invalid -sorry)?